# Javascript onChange sum input after percentage

Tags: javascript

```
<form name="cost">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Cost</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cost" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Discount</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="discount" /> (<span id="discount2"></span>)%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Net Cost</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="net" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Hello guys,
I really need a help of javascript programming. The process of the form are:

1. Put a number of in Cost
2. Then put a number of discount (auto calculates span#discount2=cost*discount/100)
3. Net cost auto update = Cost-Discount

I tried many times but have no luck plus lack of javascript knowledge. Please help.

Comment: At least put up some attempts so we can guide you on how you are messing up.

Comment: You need to upload the javascript **of your last attempt** otherwise it's likely this question will get closed.

Comment: [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) is a great hands on way to learn JavaScript, although it's pretty time consuming. There are also a ton of great tutorials on the web. If you are a more experienced programmer, I wrote [a comprehensive tutorial on JavaScript](http://adamonio.us/wexcode/66/introduction-to-javascript/) you could take a look at.

Comment: I have to echo what everyone else said. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a function to do that

```
function calculateDiscount()
{
var cost = document.getElementById('cost').value;
var discount = document.getElementById('discount').value;
//do the math
var net = cost-discount;
//update
document.getElementById('discount2').innerHTML = cost*(discount/100);
document.getElementById('net').value = net;
}
```

You'll also need to update your html, to add ID's to all elements and also call the function

```
<form name="cost">
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Cost</td><td><input type="text" id="cost" name="cost" onChange="calculateDiscount(); return false;" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Discount</td><td><input onChange="calculateDiscount(); return false;" type="text" id="discount" name="discount" /> (<span id="discount2"></span>)%</td></tr>
<tr><td>Net Cost</td><td><input type="text" name="net" id="net" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You might want to add `.toPrecision(2)` for `discount2` and `readonly="readonly"` to `input id="net"`

Comment: I have another question for this code. I have another field to add up with Net Cost. I tried to add another var to net but the result is weird. I tried : var net = cost-discount+total; with var total = document.getElementById('total').value; in <input type="text" id="total" /> but it's not work.

Comment: I tried this : `code
 function calculateDiscount()
 {
  var cost = document.getElementById('insr_total1').value;
  var total = document.getElementById('insr_total2').value;
   cost = cost.replace(/[^0-9]+/i,"");
  var discount = document.getElementById('insr_discount').value;
  //do the math
  var net = cost-discount;
  //update
  document.getElementById('insr_discount2').innerHTML = formatDollar(cost*(discount/100));
  var net1 = formatDollar(cost-cost*(discount/100));
  document.getElementById('insr_total3').value = net1+total;
 }`
but the result of insr_total3 is weird! Please help

Comment: function formatDollar(num) {
  var p = num.toFixed(2).split(".");
  return "" + p[0].split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
   return  num + (i && !(i % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
  }, "");
 }